# Detecting Touch on Bezier Path is Incorrect

Tags: swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I draw a segmented circle using UIBezier Path with this code:

```
func createCircleWithStartAndgle(startAngle: CGFloat, endAngle: CGFloat, chartSection: Int) {
    var subView = circleView
    var radius: CGFloat = circleView.bounds.size.width / 2 - 20
    var circleShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    var arcCenter = CGPoint(x: radius, y: radius)
    var bezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)



    circleShapeLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath

    circleShapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x:(subView?.bounds.midX)! - radius , y: (subView?.bounds.midY)! - radius)
    circleShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    var strokeColor = UIColor()
    switch chartSection {
    case 0:
        strokeColor = .red
        firstLayer = circleShapeLayer
        fPath = bezierPath
    case 1:
        strokeColor = .yellow
        secondLayer = circleShapeLayer
        sPath = bezierPath
    case 2:
        strokeColor = .blue
        thirdLayer = circleShapeLayer
        thPath = bezierPath
    default:
        strokeColor = .gray
    }
    circleShapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor
    circleShapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
    subView?.layer.insertSublayer(circleShapeLayer, at: UInt32(chartSection))

}
```

Which gave me a satisfied result: 
[image: Screen Shot]

Now I want to be able to touch on each segment and identify the segment, and make it bigger.

When I use this code to detect touches, it works fine for red and yellow segments (first and second path), but in order to identify blue segment, I need to tap on left upper corner or a little bit up of the blue segment. If I tap on the segment itself, it detects it as it is a first segment, not third.

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first

    guard let point = touch?.location(in: circleView) else { return }

    guard let sublayers = circleView.layer.sublayers as? [CAShapeLayer] else { return }
    for layer in sublayers {

        if let path = layer.path {
            if path == fPath.cgPath && path.contains(point) {
                print("first segment")
            } else if path == sPath.cgPath && path.contains(point) {
                print("second segment")
            } else if path == thPath.cgPath && path.contains(point) {
                print("third segment")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong? How can I correctly detect taps and modify the strokWidth of tapped bezierPath?

Comment: I have a second option you can try with it out : instead of getting segment on touch get base colour of segment and initialise checks on basis of colour ? if you like I can share piece of code required for this

Comment: I did exactly that, and it is working now. But it is not fully correct way to do that, because in my case I have three unique colors, but if I have two dark blue segments, it wouldn't identify which one is which. If anyone needs the code I can update my question and write the solution.

Comment: yes please post answer if you had done , it will help others too

Comment: if possible can you share Xcode Project file for this with answer ?